# Invoke a function with a loop of arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, loops, invoke

I have this node.js code:

```
var timeStamp = function() {
  var d = new Date();
  var year = d.getFullYear();
  var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = d.getDay();
  var hours = d.getHours();
  var minutes = d.getMinutes();
  var seconds = d.getSeconds();
  var milliseconds = d.getMilliseconds();
  var time = year + '.' + month + '.' + day + '. ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ':' + milliseconds;
  return time;
};

var tld = function() {
  var domainExtensions = ['.com', '.org'];

  for (var i=0; i<domainExtensions.length; i++) {
  return domainExtensions[i];
  }
};

// print process.argv
process.argv.forEach(function(val, index, array) {
  console.log(index + ': ' + val + '' + tld() + ' █ ' + timeStamp());
});
```

This outputting:

```
$ node index.js one two=three four
0: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe.com █ 2015.11.5. 13:45:18:187
1: c:\www\node\command-line-arguments\index.js.com █ 2015.11.5. 13:45:18:191
2: one.com █ 2015.11.5. 13:45:18:192
3: two=three.com █ 2015.11.5. 13:45:18:192
4: four.com █ 2015.11.5. 13:45:18:193
```

However what I want is to print in the console one console argument with every loop of array:

```
$ node index.js one two=three four
0: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe.com █ 2015.11.5. 13:45:18:187
1: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe.hu █ 2015.11.5. 13:45:18:187
2: c:\www\node\command-line-arguments\index.js.com █ 2015.11.5. 13:45:18:191
3: c:\www\node\command-line-arguments\index.js.hu █ 2015.11.5. 13:45:18:191
4: one.com █ 2015.11.5. 13:45:18:192
5: one.hu █ 2015.11.5. 13:45:18:192
6: two=three.com █ 2015.11.5. 13:45:18:192
7: two=three.hu █ 2015.11.5. 13:45:18:192
8: four.com █ 2015.11.5. 13:45:18:193
9: four.hu █ 2015.11.5. 13:45:18:193
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thank You for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var timeStamp = function() {
  var d = new Date();
  var year = d.getFullYear();
  var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = d.getDay();
  var hours = d.getHours();
  var minutes = d.getMinutes();
  var seconds = d.getSeconds();
  var milliseconds = d.getMilliseconds();
  var time = year + '.' + month + '.' + day + '. ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ':' + milliseconds;
  return time;
};

//better to be const
var domainExtensions = ['.com', '.org'];

// print process.argv
process.argv.forEach(function(val, index, array) {
  domainExtentions.forEach(function(tld) {
     console.log(index + ': ' + val + '' + tld + ' █ ' + timeStamp());
  });

});
```

Comment: I've got the following console error: `ReferenceError: domainExtentions is not defined`. I corrected the mistype. Now I've got another error: `ReferenceError: tld is not defined`. I corrected it (tdl -> tld) and it works. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You leave the loop when you call return. The tld function always return ".com".